# Find first matching string in two lists in less than O(n^2) time using a Java8 one-liner

Tags: java

Simple question, I have two arrays / lists, I'm looking for an efficient one-liner in Java8 to match the first argument against a long list of possible arguments.

Arguments are from `public static void main(String... args)` and the other one is from a list of predefined strings which I'll call secondArray, `["a", "b", "cc", "de", ...]`. I want to match the two incoming arrays against each other and find the first matching `arg`ument against a `secondArray` list.

Example: `args = Arrays.asList("r", "b", "c", "d", ...)`

`secondList = Arrays.asList("q", "z", "x", "c", "d", ...)`

The first matching argument would be `"c"`

The Java7 (inefficient) way of doing this would have been:

```
String profile = "default";
for (String arg : args){
    if (secondArray.contains(arg)){
        profile = arg;
        break;
    }
}

doSomethingWith(profile);
```

In Java8, this is what I've done so far, was wondering if there's a better way to do it (more efficient, faster, etc - let's assume both args and secondArray can potentially contain up to 100k entries):

```
    String profile = Arrays.stream(args)
            .filter(secondArray::contains)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("default");

    doSomethingWith(profile);
```

My assumption is that the filter doing `secondArray::contains` will mean O(n^2) complexity, since `secondArray.contains(arg)` will be called for each of the arguments. Anything closer to O(n) while still maintaining a single line of Java8 is what I'm after.

Comment: You can't do it in `O(n)` unless the two lists are already sorted.

Comment: You can certain go faster than O(n^2) can't you? If you place the secondArray into a hashmap, then you can get it to O(n).

Comment: You can sort the lists, and then do it in `O(n)`, making it `O(n log n)` overall.

Comment: Sorting would interfere with the order in which the params are passed in, is it possible to map all the params to a hashmap of some sorts which would speed up the filter ?

Comment: You can do it in `O(n)` using a `HashMap` ["assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Pathologically (as in, all values happen to have the same hash code), it could be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick to make it a one liner would be to create a set in filter cause

```
String profile = Arrays.stream(args)
            .filter(new HashSet(secondList)::contains)
            .findFirst()
            .orElse("default");
```

Such set is going to be created only once. The same instance of set will be used for each item in args.

So this code is `O(n)` to create a set and then `O(n)` to finding first arg.

---

Just keep in mind that expanded lambda like

```
.filter(arg -> new HashSet(secondList).contains(arg))
```

will create a set for each argument and will blowup complexity to `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Nooice! So the filter is actually doing what I was hoping it does. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If the second list is small, then the time complexity is not very relevant. If the second list is large, you can first put it in a HashSet:

```
 Set<String> second = new HashSet<> (secondList); //O(n)
 loop //O(n)
   if (second.contains(arg)) ... // O(1)
```

Comment: can this be done in a one-liner with Java8 ? I'm after the syntax, trying to master Streams.

Comment: Your version should work fine if you replace secondList::contains by secondSet::contains.

Comment: If I do `.filter(new HashSet(secondArray)::contains)`, will the hashset be created n number of times or just once?